# MongoDB doing $lookup on field of different types yet same content

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I know that in logTable the `"mailID"` is `"1234"` (String)

and in mailTable the `"_id"` is 1234 (NumberInt)

But is there any way at all to do this `$lookup`?

log table

```
{ 
    "_id" : "mailStuff0234", 
    "mailID" : "1234", 
    "typeState" : "NEW", 
    "changeByType" : "ADMIN" 
}
```

mail table

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(1234), 
    "user" : "torben@sunnythailand.com", 
    "subject" : "Visit to Atlantis Condo Resort"
}
```

and here is the aggregate

```
db.log.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': { typeState: 'NEW'} },
    { '$lookup': { 
        from: 'mail', 
        localField: 'mailID', 
        foreignField: '_id', 
        as: 'mail' 
    } }, 
    { '$unwind': '$mail' }
], {})
```

Comment: You can do using the lower mongodb version minimum  **mongodb 3.6**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB 4.0 introduced [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/index.html) operator so you can convert `mailID` value before applying [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html).

```
db.log.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: { mailID: { $toInt: "$mailID" } }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "mail",
            localField: "mailID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "mail"
        }
    }
])
```

You can also use [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries):

```
db.log.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "mail",
            let: { mailID: { $toInt: "$mailID" } },
            pipeline: [ { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$mailID" ] } } } ],
            as: "mail"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mickl!!!  Great solutions both of them.  Didnt know $toInt so thats VERY useful!!!

Comment: Error: findLogMail ERROR : MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$toInt' - guess I need to upgrade :D

Comment: Yes, you need 4.0 or newer